# Design of a database about Zoos

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am trying to design a database storing data about several Zoos. I just want to ask if my design is good. I know pretty well SQL and queries, but I'm not an expert at design. Requirement:

You will manage zoos, animals, food, visitors and visits. Each zoo has an id, an administrator, a name and several animals. An animal has an id, a name and date of birth; it can eat various foods, the latter consisting of an id and a name. The system stores the daily quota(integer number) for each animal and food, e.g., an animal A1 <food F1, 10; food F2, 5>; animal A2 <food F2, 1; food F5, 2>. A visitor is characterized by a personal number(an id), name and age. A visitor can visit several zoos. Such a visit is defined by a unique identifier, a day, the paid price, the visitor's personal number and the zoo id.

This is how I've done the design:

```
CREATE TABLE Zoo(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    administrator VARCHAR(30),
    name VARCHAR(40),
);

CREATE TABLE Animal(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    name VARCHAR(30),
    dob DATE,
    zoo_id INT REFERENCES Zoo(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Food(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    name VARCHAR(25)
);

CREATE TABLE DailyQuota(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    animal_id INT REFERENCES Animal(id),
    food_id INT REFERENCES Food(id),
    quantity INT
);

CREATE TABLE Visitor(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    name VARCHAR(40),
    age TINYINT
);

CREATE TABLE Visit(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    zoo_id INT REFERENCES Zoo(id),
    visitor_id INT REFERENCES Visitor(id),
    day DATE,
    paid_price SMALLINT
);
```

Want to hear any opinions

---

I also had to create a view that shows the ids of the zoos woth the smallest number of visitors. This is how I have done it:

```
GO
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW view_smallestCountVisitors
AS
    SELECT t1.zoo_id
    FROM (SELECT v.zoo_id, COUNT(v.zoo_id) MYCOUNT
            FROM Visit v
            GROUP BY v.zoo_id) t1
    WHERE t1.MYCOUNT IN (
        SELECT MIN(t2.MYCOUNT)
        FROM (SELECT v.zoo_id, COUNT(v.zoo_id) MYCOUNT
                FROM Visit v
                GROUP BY v.zoo_id) t2
        );
GO
```

It works fine but I am just wondering if this can be done in a shorter way.

Comment: Pay attention to keys. `DailyQuota` and probably `Visit` need unique constraints. For example, you can insert same `(animal_id, food_id)` combination into `DailyQuota` multiple times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there's much to say, it looks like you captured the requirements of the instructions you were given. The only small remark is when the instructions say "*a visit is defined by a unique identifier*", sometimes "**unique identifier**" is synonymous with the word **GUID** (and in some database systems **UniqueIdentifier** is the actual data type name for a **GUID**, like Microsoft SQL Server). Not sure if it's meant to be interpreted that way in this context, but figured I'd make you aware.

To answer your second question regarding shortening your view to get the `Zoo_Id` with the fewest visits, you can do the following that uses a CTE and the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
WITH CTE_ZooVisits_Sorted AS
(
    SELECT v.zoo_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(v.zoo_id), v.zoo_id) AS SortId -- Generates a unique sequential ID, ordered by the number of Zoo visits, then by the Zoo's ID to break any ties
    FROM Visit v
    GROUP BY v.zoo_id
)

SELECT zoo_id
FROM CTE_ZooVisits_Sorted
WHERE SortId = 1 -- Returns only one row with the minimum amount of Zoo Visits (ties broken by whichever Zoo was created first)
```

Note with `ROW_NUMBER()` when there's a tie, it randomly chooses which one comes first in the sort unless you provide a unique field as the *tie-breaker*, which in my example above I did by `zoo_id`. (What this logically means is if two Zoo's are tied for number of visits, the Zoo that was created first will break the tie and sorted first.) You can remove the `WHERE SortId = 1` in the final `SELECT` and replace it with an `ORDER BY SortId` to get the full list of `zoo_id` ordered by the least amount of visits to most amount of visits.

If you want an alternative where you want to sort ties in the same order without  a *tie-breaker* then instead of the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function, you can use `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` like so:

```
WITH CTE_ZooVisits_Sorted AS
(
    SELECT v.zoo_id, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(v.zoo_id)) AS SortId -- Generates a sequential ID, ordered by the number of Zoo visits, ties will have the same sequential ID generated
    FROM Visit v
    GROUP BY v.zoo_id
)

SELECT zoo_id
FROM CTE_ZooVisits_Sorted
WHERE SortId = 1 -- Returns all rows with the minimum amount of Zoo Visits (multiple rows for when there's a tie among minimum visits between multiple Zoos)
```

Note using a window function like [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [`RANK()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), or [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is additionally helpful because it lets you select any and all fields of the row that has the minimum number of zoo visits (or whatever sort criteria you want to use).

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @andrei1234589 No problem! If you have any other questions, feel free, and I'll do my best to answer them.

Comment: Hello! I have added a view in the database. I am wondering if this can be done in a shorter way

Comment: @andrei1234589 No problem, I added additional ways to re-write your view that are a little shorter, clearer, and usually more helpful in the sense that you can use this to get the entire row with the **minimum** number of visits. (Feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer so it is verified as helpful for other users browsing DBA.StackExchange who may have similar questions.)

Answer (score 13):

While you've done a pretty thorough job of following the textbook requirements, there are some practical considerations that you might or might not want to include, depending on the expectations of the assignment.  Some of these have to do with bad requirements.  I don't know if you would get extra marks or reduced marks for pointing these out.

- Food quantity as an integer is probably not precise enough
- Food quantities should have a unit of measure. Some foods will be dry, some will be liquid. Iguanas probably need a few grams of "Iguana Chow" whereas elephants will need multiple kilos of whatever they're eating.
- Amounts of money should be stored as MONEY or another non-integer data type.
- If your zoos are all over the place you might need to consider storing a currency with the monetary amount
- Storing the age of a visitor is a mistake.  Visitors age between visits.  You're better off storing the date of birth of the visitor and calculating their age at each visit, since you know the date of the visits
- In a real system, some of this information is going to be optional. Not everyone is going to tell you their date of birth.  Similarly, you may not know when your giant tortoise was born.
- People's names, if they matter, are usually stored in more than one field (e.g. given name and family name)
- It's highly unlikely that every animal will have a personal record of their dietary requirements. Some animals might, but for a lot of animals it might make more sense to store the requirements for all animals of a given species.
- The fact that animal species is not accounted for in the model is kind of questionable, since you would think that most zoos would care about something like that

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you split the animal part and the visitor part into two different schemas. They are conceptually two different domains and you can have different development and maintenance schedules.  I think mashing the two together increases complexity and complexity correlates with cost and bugs.

The separation can also help with information security. While the visitor database may need a internet facing presence (e.g. season/annual pass holder accounts), the animal part has no need to be on the internet and can have limited (or no) connectivity to internet.

I would advocate for a third schema--business operations (maintenance, inventory, purchasing). Define a data interchange standard between the different schemas (e.g. food consumption message to the business ops schema).

In my experience the "one database schema to rule them all" becomes expensive and difficult to maintain.